# Copy an enumerable to a List ? "Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyClass.Items' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass.Items>'"

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is a noob question. So if I misstate the question, it's because I am not fully understanding what is happening.

**Issue**

> Compile error: 
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyClass.Items' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

**Context**

I am in iterating a `List` through an `IOrderedEnumerable`, but I am unable to return the desired record because it is of typed `List` (since my whole app is passing `List` objects back and forth).

My input to the method is a `List`, but it seems to be implicitly cast to `IEnumerable` when I use the `OrderBy` option.

I have read everything I've found, but it all seems to boil down to:

```
// ToList is not available!
return SingleItemToCheck.ToList;
```

or

```
// same type conversion error
List<Items> ReturningList = SingleItemToCheck;
```

**The Problem Code**

```
public static List<Items> FindCheapestItem(List<Items> source)
{
    // Now we pop only the first one. 
    // ISSUE: Sometimes the top entry on the list is bad, 
    //        so we need to check it!
    var BestItemCandidate = source.OrderBy(s => s.ItemDesirability);
    bool ForgetThisOne = false;

    foreach (var SingleItemToCheck in BestItemCandidate)
    {
        ForgetThisOne = false;

        // ... test for ItemDesirability, truncated
        if (Desirability < 0)
        {
            ForgetThisOne = true;
        }

        if (!ForgetThisOne)
        {
            // we are just returning the first desirable row
            // because we are sorted on desirability
            // and consuming code can only digest a single item.
            return SingleItemToCheck;  // !!! ARGH, compile error !!!
        }
    }

    // means we looped through everything and found nothing of interest
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well why do you have `List<Items>` as return type when you are interested only in `Items` ?

Comment: Because my whole app passes lists around. Basically, I am using lists so that all the code, low and high level, looks the same and operates on lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SingleItemToCheck` is a single item, it is not a list. It does not have a `ToList()` method available. Simply create a list with that single item.

```
return new List<Items> { SingleItemToCheck };
```

Or if you're only ever interested in the one item, change the return type of the method to simply `Items` and omit the list entirely.

Another way to write that, particularly if you're only interested in the one item, is to simply refactor the inner loop logic to a function and then write a query

```
return source
         .OrderBy(s => s.ItemDesirability)
         .Where(s => IsDesirable(s)) // refactored loop logic, returning boolean
         .FirstOrDefault(); // first desirable item, or null
```

Otherwise, if you absolutely need a list, but only one item in it, consider

```
 var list =  source
         .OrderBy(s => s.ItemDesirability)
         .Where(s => IsDesirable(s))
         .Take(1)
         .ToList();
```

If no elements pass, this will be an empty list. You can then elect to return null, as your present code does, or return the empty list and let the callers deal with that instead of the null result.

Comment: Anthony: Thank you! I used the first "return new List" approach. There is actually more testing of the records, so I can't just Take(1) based on a sort (or I would!).  This solved something that I spent too much time on. I should have posted sooner!